# What are the weapons created by Sage Dadhichi's bone?

Tags: scripture, indra

I have heard a story that many weapons including Indra's Vajra was created with Sage Dadhichi's bone.

Was only one weapon (Vajra) created? If no, then I want to know exactly which weapons are created? And who have attributed them?

And is there any mention of this story in our scriptures?

Comment: I am not sure about other weapons but my answer here discusses Vajra: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2956/what-does-vajra-mean

Comment: Yes I have already read that.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani You may be interested in my question here, about a weapon created from Dadhichi's horse head: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12006/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Thanks. I have read this earlier. It discuss only about Vajra.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani No, it discusses what happened after the Vajra was created, when Indra needed one more weapon to kill Asuras with.

Comment: Apart from Vajra, Three bows are also created from Sage Dadhichi's bone. They are Sarang, Pinak, Gandeev.
One other weapon is also created, but I don't know what was it.